# Syntax-error with carousel and accordion?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, carousel

I want to use an bootstrap accordian and carousel. For initialising i use the following code, which doesn't work proberly. When i remove the 4 lines of the carousel-part, the accordion works; with this 4 lines it doesnt. Do i have a syntax-error? Thanks for any help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.carousel').carousel(
        pause: "none",
        interval: 1000
    });

    $("#accordion").accordion({
       autoHeight: false,
       collapsible: false,
       navigation: true,
       active: 0
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing a bracket on `$('.carousel').carousel(`

Change to:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    pause: "none",
    interval: 1000
});
```